# What is the symbolic meaning of "die without a sound"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

There may also be a poetic meaning, but is it purely context dependent; or is there a common connotation associated with this phrase?

My Internet searches have come up blank. Would it be reasonable to give it the opposite meaning of **"died with an awful sound"**? From "Smoke on the Water"

Comment: Please show what internet searches you have done, in order to indicate what others need not attempt for themselves.

Comment: @AndrewLeach just as I have shown in the title by using quotation marks around the phrase. It hasn't shown anything.

Comment: I searched for `"die without a sound" analysis` and [the first result](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=p2Yh6HQKecsC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq="die+without+a+sound) may help here. See the top and bottom of page 134.

Comment: Thank you @AndrewLeach "they die as they lived, without a sound" gives me something to go on :)

Answer (score -1):

To die without a sound would often be understood as the subject's death going unnoticed. It could be talking about the near future, such as other people not noticing the subject is dead. Could also mean something in the longer future, such as the death not having an impact